# Uniquely identifying ManyToMany relationships in Django

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm trying to figure out how best to uniquely identify a ManyToMany relationship in my Django application. I have models similar to the following:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    countries = models.ManyToManyField('Country', blank=True)

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    geo = models.ForeignKey('Geo', db_index=True)

class Geo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I use the `ManyToManyField` type for the `countries` field because I want to avoid city name duplication (i.e. there may be a city name like "Springfield" that appears in multiple locations).

In another place in my application, I want to be able to uniquely identify the city-country-geography relationship. That is, I need to know that a user whose city is "Springfield" resides in the United States, versus Canada, for example. As a result, I need to know which of the `ManyToManyField` relationships my city maps to. My user looks something like this:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    # ... other fields ...
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

This setup clearly does not capture the relationship between city and country properly. What's the best way to capture the unique relationship? Would I use a custom [through-table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) with an `AutoField` acting as a key, and change my user to point to that through-table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your idea of a `through` table is the right approach. Then, I would add a `unique_together('city', 'country')` into the `Meta`.

I don't think there is a need for an `AutoField`

Comment: Does the `geo` really need to be in the through table? A country can only ever be in one geo, hence the `ForeignKey` reference. I feel like I could get the geo as necessary through a simple join...